# owl carousal is broken when html called from laravel controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

owl carousal works nicely when I put HTML in laravel view blade :

[image]

But when I am trying to make ajax call (by json response, getting HTML from the controller), It's broken :
[image]

My codes from blade : (getting data in searchResult id by ajax call)

```
        <div class="owl-carousel bootcamp-slider" id="searchResult">

        </div>
        <div class="bootcamp-slider-btn owl-controls">
            <div class="owl-nav">
                <div class="owl-prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
               </div>
                <div class="owl-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-dots">
                <div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
                <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
                <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

codes from controller :

```
foreach($data as $bootcamp){
               $output .= '
                    <div class="bootcamp-card">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-12 bootcamp-body">
                                <div class="bootcamp-thumbnail">
                                    <img style="width:100%!important;height:100%!important"
                                         src="img/cart/course-thumb.png" alt="">
                                </div>

                                ....
                                ....
                                ....
                                <div class="p-0 pt-2 d-flex">
                                    <a href="#" class="form-control book-button" style="text- 
                               align: center;"
                                       data-toggle="modal"
                                       data-target="#bootcamp-registration">Book now</a>
                                    <a href="cart" class="add-to-cart">Add to cart</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               ';
           }
        }else{
             $output .= '
                 <div>No Bootcamp found</div>
             ';
        }

        $data = array(
            'searched_bootcamp' => $output
        );

        echo json_encode($data);
```

Please check the code from jquery, I am trying to minimize code as much as possible:

```
$('select').on('change',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            let by_month= $('#by-month').val();
            let by_course = $('#by-course').val();

            searchBootcamp(by_month, by_course);
        })

        function searchBootcamp(by_month = '', by_course = ''){
           $.ajax({
               url : "search-bootcamp",
               type : "GET",
               dataType : "JSON",
               data : {by_month : by_month, by_course : by_course},
               success : function(data){
                   $('#searchResult').html(data.searched_bootcamp);
               }
           }).done(function() {
               $('.bootcamp-slider').owlCarousel()
           });
        }
        searchBootcamp();
```

Comment: Does it any jquery error? Have you checked console

Comment: no, it does not give any jquery error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must reactive `owl carousal` after add html from ajax.
After ajax add new html, 1 time call `owl carousal` init

Example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  // add html to body
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

---

When multiple replace html you can destroy and re-init
Example:

```
let owl = $(".bootcamp-slider");
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  // add html to body
  if (!owl.hasClass('owl-loaded')) {
    owl.owlCarousel();
  } else {
    owl.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');
    owl.owlCarousel();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot, But its working for only the first request, when I am 0nchanging select, it's returning the same issue, I am sharing my jquery at the bottom of my post

Comment: see my edit answer